# Is it possible to load and parse file on remote server?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

Is it possible to download and parse a plain text file from different domain with JavaScript?

I've got this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLRd9/2/) so far, but I'm stuck figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Markup:

```
  <div id="clickme">Click me</div>
  <div id="result">Result: </div>
```

Code:

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  /* ###################################
     NOTE: im on say example.com/test.html but trying
     NOTE: to access different_domain_sample.com
   */
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var sURL = "http://www.google.com/robots.txt";

  req.open("GET", sURL, true);
  req.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "blah/4.2");

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        $("#result").text("Result is: <pre>" + req.responseText + "</pre>");
    }
  };
  req.send(null);
});
```

Already answered, but more info on this is here [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: You can't send requests across domains via JavaScript.

Comment: @Blender Is this same limitation as in java's applets? Can I "sign" the code or ask for user whether he trusts the code, so its possible to access files across domains or something like that?

Comment: @lzdt: Yes, that would be possible. Or do it like ninja suggests, by hosting a proxy service on the same domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

1. With the help of a non-browser-based proxy served from your domain which will fetch the data on your behalf. You can also use a plugin which can bypass the same-origin policy.
2. Use JSONP or another similarly hackish way around the same-origin policy. This would require the web server to support JSONP.
3. Disable the cross-origin policy (*definitely not recommended*; *very dangerous*)

Comment: Ughh, ok, Got it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Workarounds thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

It's because of browsers have implemented a feature called cross-site-scripting-prevention. You could for example do the ajax request on a php file on the same server and in that query the target page using curl.

Comment: Just as I would have written.